# Manipulate element onclick base on data-target

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

So I'm trying to make a button which toggles the visibility of a div element. But the approach would be getting the value of `data-target` of the button and manipulate the correspoding div element that has an `id` equal to the data-target value. I'm doing this so I could reuse the javascript function to different buttons that has their own corresponding div element to toggle visibility.

so far here is my html code

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="nav-brand">
                <img src="{{ asset('logo_brandmark.png') }}" alt="logo_brandmark.png" class="nav-brandmark"><span class="nav-wordmark">{{ config('app.name', 'app name') }}</span>
            </a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="navAuth" onclick="btnToggleVisibility(this)"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="navAuth">
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="auth-link btn btn-primary">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="auth-link btn btn-info">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and this is the external javascript

```
function btnToggleVisibility(obj) {
    var targetElement = obj.getAttribute('data-target');

    targetElement.classList.toggle('show');
}

window.btnToggleVisibility = btnToggleVisibility;
```

when I click on the button, it shows this error
[image]

Comment: When I do

function btnToggleVisibility(obj) {
    var targetElement = obj.getAttribute('data-target');

    console.log(targetElement);
}
it shows the correct value of the `data-target` as expected but the `targetElement.classList.toggle('show')` doesn't seem to manipulate the element with the id equal to the `data-target` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the element that corresponds to the id value

```
function btnToggleVisibility(obj) {
    var targetElement = document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-target'));

    targetElement.classList.toggle('show');
}

window.btnToggleVisibility = btnToggleVisibility;
```

Comment: Ohh I see, now I get it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also read `data-*` attribute values using the [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that is available on the element.

You could also restructure how you're going about this so that you're not defining or attaching the `toggle` directly on elements using the global `onclick` event handler. Might make future changes simpler for you if things are in a centralised location.

For example, you could achieve your outcome as follows:

```
// the CSS class we'll toggle
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```
// the html
<button type="button" class="toggler" data-target="#div-1">Show/Hide</button>
<div class="hidden" id="div-1">
    <p>This is the content that will be toggled</p>
</div>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    // define the function that will toggle the targets visibility using the .hidden class
    function toggleTargetVisibility(e) {
        // get all elements that match the target data-* attribute value
        // there may or may not be more than one element
        let div = document.querySelectorAll(e.dataset.target);

        // toggle the .hidden class for each found element
        div.forEach(function(el) {
            el.classList.toggle('hidden');
        })
    }

    // get all elements that will be responsible for triggering the toggle function
    let togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');

    // attach the onclick event to each found toggler element
    togglers.forEach(function(toggler) {
        toggler.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            toggleTargetVisibility(e.target);
        });
    })
})
```